# ASP.NET Visual Studio 2013 extremely slow debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have an ASP.NET Application I want to debug on localhost. When I run it without debugging, it runs very fast and smoothly, with about 3 seconds per page load. However, when I try to debug the app with Visual Studio and Chrome or Firefox, every page load takes about 20-30 or even 40 seconds to load, which is extremely slow. I have tried everything I found on the internet about these issues, yet none seems to help me out:

- "Load all Symbols" from Microsoft Symbol servers, then uncheck that location
- Delete all breakpoints
- Uncheck "Enable property evaluation"
- Other options I can't recall

Which is a good debugging configuration for asp.net apps? Any extra suggestions that may help?

Thank you very much and kind regards,

David

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your visual studio is using a lot of memory. You should try to turn off the browserlink which will reduce the amount of memory being allocated. It is still fine to disable the browserling and the preview still works.

Here is a guide and explanation
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

It is also possible that you have a lot of data or calculation to be ran in your form load.

Another possibility is a slow internet connection, this only applies if you have items or scripts on your page the are from an external source like JavaScript, CSS etc.